Select all product rows for which the price does not change among rows sharing the same description
Assume you have a table called ProductsTable with a structure as follows:
ProductID: int (key)
ProductDesc: varchar
Price: int

Now, assume that the ProductDesc CAN be equal throughout the rows.  So, you could have two products with the same name, say "APPLE".  However, their prices can be different.  (This ends up making sense with our design, since there are a lot of other columns I didn't mention which have other data, so the price and description could be the same but other elements of the products are different.)
I would simply like to find all ProductID where the ProductDesc is the same among all of them, AND the price is the same for all of them.  In other words, the price doesn't change for the same product. I would like to find any products which don't have a variable price.
Apple 5.0
Apple 5.0
Apple 5.0
Pear 3.0
Pear 4.0

In the above data example, I would return only the productIds corresponding to Apple, and not Pear, since Pear's price changes between entries.
I think this requires a CTE and/or some usage of StdDev, but I'm not sure how to put the syntax together.  Here's my attempt at psuedocode:
SELECT a.* FROM ProductsTable a WHERE a.Price = (SELECT b.ProductPrice FROM ProductsTable b WHERE b.ProductDesc LIKE a.ProductDesc)

But I think that will only compare the first two rows.  I would like to find all products which don't have a varying price at all, between all rows having the same productDesc.

FWIW I never figured this question out, so if anyone sees it in the future feel free to try to take a crack at a solution.  It ended up being okay as we went with a different solution/needs for our requirement, but I feel this is still a very useful and common thing which probably comes up.

Might select ids of products with unchanged price, then get info about those ids, like:
SELECT a.* FROM ProductsTable a 
WHERE a.ProductID IN (
                      SELECT ProductID FROM ProductsTable
                      GROUP BY ProductID 
                      HAVING MIN(Price) = MAX(Price))


This gave me an idea to use DISTINCT Within the Having clause.  Something like HAVING COUNT(Distinct Price) = 0 ... still trying to figure it out but appreciate the comment

COUNT(Distinct Price) = 1... obviously you will never have 0 unless you have NULL price...
